# Aspx Database initializer gives error while attempting to migrate an already updated database

Tags: asp.net, database, entity-framework, initializer

I am trying to set the initialization of my db by code, so that when the application is deployed the database is updated to the latest migration.
My DB Context is as follows:

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationDbContext, MyDbMigrationsConfiguration>());

    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Topic>().ToTable("Topics");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Attachment>().ToTable("Attachments");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Subscription>().ToTable("Subscriptions");
    }

    public DbSet<Topic> Topics { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
}
```

}

My Migration configuration is this:

```
internal sealed class MyDbMigrationsConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public MyDbMigrationsConfiguration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {}
}
```

And in my startup I have:

```
public partial class Startup {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
        ConfigureAuth(app);

        using (var dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            dbContext.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
            dbContext.Database.Initialize(force: false);

        }

    }
}
```

Now when I call dbContext.Database.Initialize(force: false); I am getting an error about one of the tables being already existing.
But I thought the initializer should check whether the database is already updated or not and apply the migrations accordingly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: see this answer that may help, https://stackoverflow.com/a/41093300/2374987

Comment: If I try to update the database through console command: Update-Database, I get the same error. It seems the migrations are still considered pending, after being applied

Comment: you have to undo latest migration and redo it